# Any reason why Reputation is not shown as title tooltip when Question is put on hold?

Tags: discussion, reputation

[Check here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489874/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-into-t-string)

Hi,

I am talking about a scenario where title tooltip of reputation is not displayed. Almost everywhere on Stackoverflow, we see tooltip when I hover over it. May I know if there is any reason behind not showing it here?

If you didnt get it, Check here.

[image: check here]

Thanks.

Comment: When a question is put on hold does the reputation of the users who did it matter?

Comment: They are all >3k right?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Not necessarily.  Mods without 3k can vote to close too.

Comment: @Servy Oh yeah I forgot about that.  I'm just so used to seeing mods with >3k rep.

Comment: Note that in review queue entries you've voted on or that are completed, rep doesn't show up for past reviewers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't read the mind of the SE developers. This being said, looking at a close-voter's reputation is really focusing on the wrong thing. Either the question should be closed, in which case the close-voters voted correctly, or the question should not be closed, in which case if you want to argue for reopening your focus should be on explaining why the question should be reopened, and not on the reputation of those who voted to close.

I've seen users with very high rep who **clearly** had no clue as to what constitutes an appropriate question for SO. Some of them would post external resource requests with wild abandon. They were wrong, despite their high reputation.

And if you must focus on the wrong thing, you can always click on the link to the user's profile where you can get the user's reputation, and a whole bunch of other details.

Comment: Isn't that argument sort of true everywhere though? Is there ever really a time where one **should** scrutinize the reputation score of a user, when evaluating something they've done?

Comment: Yes, that's generally true. It would be perfectly fine with me if hovering over a user's name in comments would not show the reputation or if the reputation were not automatically visible in the flair attached to posts.