# No reputation displayed when hovering over a close vote user's name

Tags: feature-request, display-names

This is a really minor thing, but if I hover over *Pointy* in the below example, I see their reputation:

> [image: Pointy's reputation]

If, however, I hover over *Alex K*, I see no such information:

> [image: Alex K's lack of reputation]

Can reputation be added to the element's `title` attribute wherever a username is displayed?

Comment: This is also the case for the delete voters. 10K link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601244/rcpp-weirdly-slow-in-loop-compare-to-r

Comment: Related question here: [Any reason why Reputation is not shown as title tooltip when Question is put on hold?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295410/any-reason-why-reputation-is-not-shown-as-title-tooltip-when-question-is-put-on). Feature request on Meta SE here: [Show reputation while hovering names in the hold/close notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190196/show-reputation-while-hovering-names-in-the-hold-close-notification).